# How many magnetic latitude degrees would 100 km correspond to?

Tags: magnetic-fields, distance

I'm trying to make a notation (an ionospheric plasma bubble) on a digram true to scale. I know the bubble is 100 km wide but the diagram has magnetic latitude and longitude for the axes.

How many (magnetic) degrees would correspond to 100 km? (Near the magnetic equator)

Comment: From the original design of the meter: 90 degrees is 10 000 km (distance from a pole to the equator).

Answer (score 0):

Near the equator, 1 degree is about 111 km. So 100 km is about 0.9 degrees.  This will change for longitude though as you change the latitude.

Comment: In reality, the Earth's magnetic poles are not exactly opposite each other, so there is some longitude dependence in this conversion.